# How to loop a json object's value using jquery ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, jquery

How to loop through the json data whose value contains HTML returned from ajax call in Jquery.Example : I want to count the number of li tags in the below data with a specified class.

I need to count number of li tags that have coded_false and ITcoded_false together.Also, I should be able to count li tags individual counts .As in, count number of itcoded_true, coded_true,coded_false,itcoded_false.

please help me out . Thanks!

```
 $.ajax({
     url: ROOT_PATH + "/test_descriptions/get_table_counts/" + id + '.json',
     type: "get",
     data: {
         dataset_id: dataset_id
     },
     success: function (data) {
         data2 = data.coded_true

     }

 });

 }
```

Below is the value of json data that I get from controller.

```
{"coded_true":"<ul class='tp_info'></ul><ul class='tp_info'><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The sldodialogs.responseoptimization.OptimizationSection.optimize\n         method solves the optimization problem using the parallel pool if the\n         UseParallel option is set to 'always'.</li></ul><ul class='tp_info'><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The optimize command throws a warning if the UseParallel option\n         is set to 'always' and the OptimizedModel option is empty.</li><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The optimize command throws an error if the UseParallel option is\n         set to 'always', the OptimizeModel options is not empty, and the model\n         specified by the OptimizeModel option is dirty.</li></ul><ul class='tp_info'><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The patternsearch solver uses the parallel pool to evaluate\n         candidate solutions in the poll and search sets.</li><li class='coded_true ITcoded_true'>The CPU consumption on workers should increase at the same rate\n         as the master CPU when optimization runs with patternsearch solver in the\n         parallel mode. g860087</li></ul><ul class='tp_info'><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The initParallel method is a protected method.</li><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The initParallel method checks for any Simulink models that\n         are used during optimization and makes sure they are not dirty.</li><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The initParallel method initializes the parallel pool workers by\n         calling the parallelsim.setupWorkers utility. The Options.OptimizedModel\n         and Options.ParallelPathDependencies properties are passed to\n         setupWorkers.</li><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The finishParallel method is a protected method.</li><li class='coded_true ITcoded_false'>The finishParallel method restores the MATLABPOOL workers by\n         calling the parallelsim.cleanupWorkers utility.</li></ul>
```

Comment: you have an extra `}` in your ajax at the end.  For the counting i'd recommend using Regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery to count number of li containing in some text you can do it in a following way:

var someHTML = data2 = data.coded_true;

> $(someHTML).find("li").length;

Consider [jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2)